# Representation of Set in java versus CQL

Tags: java, cassandra, cql

I'm new in cassandra and I try to add to a table a set of data. My table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (id int, name varchar, mySet set<uuid>, PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

The problem that I met is when I do my request the type are not compatible, the string representation of a set in Java is [uuid1,uuid2,...] and the representation in cql is {'uuid1','uuid2',...}

```
session.execute("INSERT INTO myTable (id , name, mySet) VALUES (" + myID + ", '" + myName +"' ," + mySet + ");");
```

So do you know guys if there is a function or a library which will directly fix this problem. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of appending the set contents to the query string (which uses the set .toString() implementation) you could instead do the following (cassandra 2.0+ required):

```
session.execute("INSERT INTO myTable (id, name, mySet) VALUES (?, ?, ?));", myId, myName, mySet);
```

The driver will then take care of injecting the Set properly for you.  You could also consider using a [BoundStatement](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/2.0/java-driver/quick_start/qsSimpleClientBoundStatements_t.html) or [QueryBuilder](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/2.0/java-driver/reference/queryBuilder_r.html) to accomplish this as well.

Answer (score 3):

I would also recommend you to use prepared statements as well. Besides other reasons, C* does a bunch of work it will cache for any query if it's a p_stmnt, making those faster next time you issue them. Not using p_stmnts will make c* repeat that work over and over again instead of using the cache.